# CSS is it possible to position a table on top of another table?

Tags: css

I got two tables one below the other. I want to move it up so it covers a bit of the top table. can i do that with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second table,

Try:

```
margin-top: -50px
```

Or:

```
position: relative;
top: -50px;
```

But Tables are sometime tricky to style (you should do some tests in different browsers)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for example `margin-top: -24px` to the second table.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/NSVz2/)